# What happens when you run exec csh in a UNIX shell and why?

Tags: shell, unix, exec

Question is just in the title: What happens when you run `exec csh` in a UNIX shell and why?

Comment: Is this a homework/assignment question? Did you read the manual page for exec?

Answer (score 1):

The `exec` command replaces the current process with the one specified, so the Unix Shell stops being a Unix Shell and suddenly becomes the C Shell (`csh`, which just so happens to be a kind of Unix Shell). Why? That's just the de facto standard.

Answer (score 1):

`exec` will replace the current shell process with a new process. If you skip this the command you enter will be started as a child and return back to your shell when you exit the child. It expects the executable to start as the first argument.

`csh` (the first argument) is the name of a executable. It will be searched in `PATH`. Typically it finds a system installed C Shell (like `/bin/csh`) or a C Shell clone (like tcsh installed under the legacy name).

So effectively you are replacing your current shell session with a C Shell. And unless you are a bearded Unix guru you don't want that - ever. Normally a C Shell has a `%` prompt instead of `>` in Posix or Bourne Shells.

You can recover from it by logging out. Next time you login the normal default shell (which is most likely not csh) will be started. To make the switch of a shell permanent the `chsh` (change shell) command is used.